# MongoDB Exclude documents from the find result based on the values of a subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection of products. Each product contains an array of history items.

```
{
    "_id" : "product1"
    "name" : "Product 1",
    "history" : [
        {
                "date" : "2017-09-18 11:49:03.000",
                "processed" : 0,
                "status": "New"
        },
        {
                "date" : "2017-09-18 11:49:03.000",
                "processed" : 0,
                "diff": []
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "product2"
    "name" : "Product 2",
    "history" : [
        {
                "date" : "2017-09-18 11:49:03.000",
                "processed" : 1,
                "status": "New"
        },
        {
                "date" : "2017-09-18 11:49:03.000",
                "processed" : 0,
                "diff": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I can find all the products that are new and have history that hasn't been processed by using the following mongoDB query:

```
db.products.find(
    {
        "history": {
            $elemMatch: {
                "processed": {$eq: 0},
                "status": {$eq: "New"}
            }
        }
    }
)
```

But I can't figure out how to find the ones where:

- It has a history item that needs to be processed `"processed": {$eq: 0}`
- Does not contain a history item which has a status of "new" and a processed value of "0"

So it should bring back "product2" and not "product1" as product1 needs to be handled differently.

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting only `product 1` in output because you are doing an `and` search for both `processed` and `status` fields which match only `product 1`. If you want `product 2` in out as well based only on `processed` field then you need to use `$or` query.

Check following query it will return both `product 1` and `product 2`

```
{
     "history": {
         $elemMatch: {
            $or:[
              {"processed": {$eq: 0}},
              {"status": {$eq: "New"}}]
         }
     }
}
```

Updated the query based on your explanation in comments.

```
.find({
    $and:[{
        "history": {
            $not: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "processed": {$eq: 0},
                    "status":{$eq: "New"}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {"history.processed":0}
]})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually need two queries (I want to handle them separately) one that will return just `product1` which I can do with the query in my question but I can't figure out how to return just `product2` in a separate query based on the fact that its history item for status new has been processed but it's got another history item that hasn't been processed. I always get `product1` as well!

Comment: so is it always `product 1` and `product 2` or you want some query on some other parameters. can you please explain this in a little bit more detail.

Comment: There will be over 1000 products in the collection in total, that are imported from a separate system. I am importing these into mongo and tracking the changes as history items. I want to be able to retrieve through two different queries: - 1st Query: Products that have a status of new (this i can do with the query in my question) (product 1 only) - 2nd query: Products that have history items that need to be exported processed=0 but don't have a status new history item that needs exporting (product 2 only). So i want to find history items where processed=0 and none of those have status=new

Comment: `none of those have status=new` means in any of the items in `history` array? In your example above both product have one item in array which has `processed=0` and none of them have `status=new` --- `{
                "date" : "2017-09-18 11:49:03.000",
                "processed" : 0,
                "diff": []
        }` thats the reason it is returning both `product 1` and `product 2`

Comment: Product 2 has "processed" : 1 and "status": "New" whereas product 1 has "processed" : 0 and "status": "New". In mysql I guess it would be something like `Where history.processed = 0 AND NOT (history.processed = 0 AND history.status = 'new')`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. Sorry I didn't explain what I was trying to achieve very well. I would upvote as well if i could...